# Match any UTF-8 letter in javacc regular expression

Tags: regex, utf-8, javacc, letter

How can i write regular expression in javacc that matches any UTF-8 letter? I red that some regular expression engines support \p{L} but this doesn't work in javacc or i am doing something wrong.

`TOKEN : { < #UTF_LETTER : \p{L} > }`

Comment: If `[\\u00C0-\\u00D6]`-like ranges are allowed, check [how the `pL` varaible in this answer is defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151039/allow-aphricates-in-this-regex/35151099#35151099).

Comment: Yeah this should do the trick. I will try and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is an answer thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew. You need to paste pL var into javacc code yourself like this:

```
TOKEN : { < #UTF_LETTER : [
"a"-"z", 
"A"-"Z", 
"\u00AA",
"\u00B5",
"\u00BA",
"\u00C0"-"\u00D6",
"\u00D8"-"\u00F6",
"\u00F8"-"\u02C1",
"\u02C6"-"\u02D1",
"\u02E0"-"\u02E4",
"\u02EC",
"\u02EE",
"\u0370"-"\u0374",
"\u0376",
"\u0377",
"\u037A"-"\u037D",
"\u037F",
"\u0386",
"\u0388"-"\u038A",
"\u038C",
"\u038E"-"\u03A1",
"\u03A3"-"\u03F5",
"\u03F7"-"\u0481",
"\u048A"-"\u052F",
"\u0531"-"\u0556",
"\u0559",
"\u0561"-"\u0587",
"\u05D0"-"\u05EA",
"\u05F0"-"\u05F2",
"\u0620"-"\u064A",
"\u066E",
"\u066F",
"\u0671"-"\u06D3",
"\u06D5",
"\u06E5",
"\u06E6",
"\u06EE",
"\u06EF",
"\u06FA"-"\u06FC",
"\u06FF",
"\u0710",
"\u0712"-"\u072F",
"\u074D"-"\u07A5",
"\u07B1",
"\u07CA"-"\u07EA",
"\u07F4",
"\u07F5",
"\u07FA",
"\u0800"-"\u0815",
"\u081A",
"\u0824",
"\u0828",
"\u0840"-"\u0858",
"\u08A0"-"\u08B2",
"\u0904"-"\u0939",
"\u093D",
"\u0950",
"\u0958"-"\u0961",
"\u0971"-"\u0980",
"\u0985"-"\u098C",
"\u098F",
"\u0990",
"\u0993"-"\u09A8",
"\u09AA"-"\u09B0",
"\u09B2",
"\u09B6"-"\u09B9",
"\u09BD",
"\u09CE",
"\u09DC",
"\u09DD",
"\u09DF"-"\u09E1",
"\u09F0",
"\u09F1",
"\u0A05"-"\u0A0A",
"\u0A0F",
"\u0A10",
"\u0A13"-"\u0A28",
"\u0A2A"-"\u0A30",
"\u0A32",
"\u0A33",
"\u0A35",
"\u0A36",
"\u0A38",
"\u0A39",
"\u0A59"-"\u0A5C",
"\u0A5E",
"\u0A72"-"\u0A74",
"\u0A85"-"\u0A8D",
"\u0A8F"-"\u0A91",
"\u0A93"-"\u0AA8",
"\u0AAA"-"\u0AB0",
"\u0AB2",
"\u0AB3",
"\u0AB5"-"\u0AB9",
"\u0ABD",
"\u0AD0",
"\u0AE0",
"\u0AE1",
"\u0B05"-"\u0B0C",
"\u0B0F",
"\u0B10",
"\u0B13"-"\u0B28",
"\u0B2A"-"\u0B30",
"\u0B32",
"\u0B33",
"\u0B35"-"\u0B39",
"\u0B3D",
"\u0B5C",
"\u0B5D",
"\u0B5F"-"\u0B61",
"\u0B71",
"\u0B83",
"\u0B85"-"\u0B8A",
"\u0B8E"-"\u0B90",
"\u0B92"-"\u0B95",
"\u0B99",
"\u0B9A",
"\u0B9C",
"\u0B9E",
"\u0B9F",
"\u0BA3",
"\u0BA4",
"\u0BA8"-"\u0BAA",
"\u0BAE"-"\u0BB9",
"\u0BD0",
"\u0C05"-"\u0C0C",
"\u0C0E"-"\u0C10",
"\u0C12"-"\u0C28",
"\u0C2A"-"\u0C39",
"\u0C3D",
"\u0C58",
"\u0C59",
"\u0C60",
"\u0C61",
"\u0C85"-"\u0C8C",
"\u0C8E"-"\u0C90",
"\u0C92"-"\u0CA8",
"\u0CAA"-"\u0CB3",
"\u0CB5"-"\u0CB9",
"\u0CBD",
"\u0CDE",
"\u0CE0",
"\u0CE1",
"\u0CF1",
"\u0CF2",
"\u0D05"-"\u0D0C",
"\u0D0E"-"\u0D10",
"\u0D12"-"\u0D3A",
"\u0D3D",
"\u0D4E",
"\u0D60",
"\u0D61",
"\u0D7A"-"\u0D7F",
"\u0D85"-"\u0D96",
"\u0D9A"-"\u0DB1",
"\u0DB3"-"\u0DBB",
"\u0DBD",
"\u0DC0"-"\u0DC6",
"\u0E01"-"\u0E30",
"\u0E32",
"\u0E33",
"\u0E40"-"\u0E46",
"\u0E81",
"\u0E82",
"\u0E84",
"\u0E87",
"\u0E88",
"\u0E8A",
"\u0E8D",
"\u0E94"-"\u0E97",
"\u0E99"-"\u0E9F",
"\u0EA1"-"\u0EA3",
"\u0EA5",
"\u0EA7",
"\u0EAA",
"\u0EAB",
"\u0EAD"-"\u0EB0",
"\u0EB2",
"\u0EB3",
"\u0EBD",
"\u0EC0"-"\u0EC4",
"\u0EC6",
"\u0EDC"-"\u0EDF",
"\u0F00",
"\u0F40"-"\u0F47",
"\u0F49"-"\u0F6C",
"\u0F88"-"\u0F8C",
"\u1000"-"\u102A",
"\u103F",
"\u1050"-"\u1055",
"\u105A"-"\u105D",
"\u1061",
"\u1065",
"\u1066",
"\u106E"-"\u1070",
"\u1075"-"\u1081",
"\u108E",
"\u10A0"-"\u10C5",
"\u10C7",
"\u10CD",
"\u10D0"-"\u10FA",
"\u10FC"-"\u1248",
"\u124A"-"\u124D",
"\u1250"-"\u1256",
"\u1258",
"\u125A"-"\u125D",
"\u1260"-"\u1288",
"\u128A"-"\u128D",
"\u1290"-"\u12B0",
"\u12B2"-"\u12B5",
"\u12B8"-"\u12BE",
"\u12C0",
"\u12C2"-"\u12C5",
"\u12C8"-"\u12D6",
"\u12D8"-"\u1310",
"\u1312"-"\u1315",
"\u1318"-"\u135A",
"\u1380"-"\u138F",
"\u13A0"-"\u13F4",
"\u1401"-"\u166C",
"\u166F"-"\u167F",
"\u1681"-"\u169A",
"\u16A0"-"\u16EA",
"\u16F1"-"\u16F8",
"\u1700"-"\u170C",
"\u170E"-"\u1711",
"\u1720"-"\u1731",
"\u1740"-"\u1751",
"\u1760"-"\u176C",
"\u176E"-"\u1770",
"\u1780"-"\u17B3",
"\u17D7",
"\u17DC",
"\u1820"-"\u1877",
"\u1880"-"\u18A8",
"\u18AA",
"\u18B0"-"\u18F5",
"\u1900"-"\u191E",
"\u1950"-"\u196D",
"\u1970"-"\u1974",
"\u1980"-"\u19AB",
"\u19C1"-"\u19C7",
"\u1A00"-"\u1A16",
"\u1A20"-"\u1A54",
"\u1AA7",
"\u1B05"-"\u1B33",
"\u1B45"-"\u1B4B",
"\u1B83"-"\u1BA0",
"\u1BAE",
"\u1BAF",
"\u1BBA"-"\u1BE5",
"\u1C00"-"\u1C23",
"\u1C4D"-"\u1C4F",
"\u1C5A"-"\u1C7D",
"\u1CE9"-"\u1CEC",
"\u1CEE"-"\u1CF1",
"\u1CF5",
"\u1CF6",
"\u1D00"-"\u1DBF",
"\u1E00"-"\u1F15",
"\u1F18"-"\u1F1D",
"\u1F20"-"\u1F45",
"\u1F48"-"\u1F4D",
"\u1F50"-"\u1F57",
"\u1F59",
"\u1F5B",
"\u1F5D",
"\u1F5F"-"\u1F7D",
"\u1F80"-"\u1FB4",
"\u1FB6"-"\u1FBC",
"\u1FBE",
"\u1FC2"-"\u1FC4",
"\u1FC6"-"\u1FCC",
"\u1FD0"-"\u1FD3",
"\u1FD6"-"\u1FDB",
"\u1FE0"-"\u1FEC",
"\u1FF2"-"\u1FF4",
"\u1FF6"-"\u1FFC",
"\u2071",
"\u207F",
"\u2090"-"\u209C",
"\u2102",
"\u2107",
"\u210A"-"\u2113",
"\u2115",
"\u2119"-"\u211D",
"\u2124",
"\u2126",
"\u2128",
"\u212A"-"\u212D",
"\u212F"-"\u2139",
"\u213C"-"\u213F",
"\u2145"-"\u2149",
"\u214E",
"\u2183",
"\u2184",
"\u2C00"-"\u2C2E",
"\u2C30"-"\u2C5E",
"\u2C60"-"\u2CE4",
"\u2CEB"-"\u2CEE",
"\u2CF2",
"\u2CF3",
"\u2D00"-"\u2D25",
"\u2D27",
"\u2D2D",
"\u2D30"-"\u2D67",
"\u2D6F",
"\u2D80"-"\u2D96",
"\u2DA0"-"\u2DA6",
"\u2DA8"-"\u2DAE",
"\u2DB0"-"\u2DB6",
"\u2DB8"-"\u2DBE",
"\u2DC0"-"\u2DC6",
"\u2DC8"-"\u2DCE",
"\u2DD0"-"\u2DD6",
"\u2DD8"-"\u2DDE",
"\u2E2F",
"\u3005",
"\u3006",
"\u3031"-"\u3035",
"\u303B",
"\u303C",
"\u3041"-"\u3096",
"\u309D"-"\u309F",
"\u30A1"-"\u30FA",
"\u30FC"-"\u30FF",
"\u3105"-"\u312D",
"\u3131"-"\u318E",
"\u31A0"-"\u31BA",
"\u31F0"-"\u31FF",
"\u3400"-"\u4DB5",
"\u4E00"-"\u9FCC",
"\uA000"-"\uA48C",
"\uA4D0"-"\uA4FD",
"\uA500"-"\uA60C",
"\uA610"-"\uA61F",
"\uA62A",
"\uA62B",
"\uA640"-"\uA66E",
"\uA67F"-"\uA69D",
"\uA6A0"-"\uA6E5",
"\uA717"-"\uA71F",
"\uA722"-"\uA788",
"\uA78B"-"\uA78E",
"\uA790"-"\uA7AD",
"\uA7B0",
"\uA7B1",
"\uA7F7"-"\uA801",
"\uA803"-"\uA805",
"\uA807"-"\uA80A",
"\uA80C"-"\uA822",
"\uA840"-"\uA873",
"\uA882"-"\uA8B3",
"\uA8F2"-"\uA8F7",
"\uA8FB",
"\uA90A"-"\uA925",
"\uA930"-"\uA946",
"\uA960"-"\uA97C",
"\uA984"-"\uA9B2",
"\uA9CF",
"\uA9E0"-"\uA9E4",
"\uA9E6"-"\uA9EF",
"\uA9FA"-"\uA9FE",
"\uAA00"-"\uAA28",
"\uAA40"-"\uAA42",
"\uAA44"-"\uAA4B",
"\uAA60"-"\uAA76",
"\uAA7A",
"\uAA7E"-"\uAAAF",
"\uAAB1",
"\uAAB5",
"\uAAB6",
"\uAAB9"-"\uAABD",
"\uAAC0",
"\uAAC2",
"\uAADB"-"\uAADD",
"\uAAE0"-"\uAAEA",
"\uAAF2"-"\uAAF4",
"\uAB01"-"\uAB06",
"\uAB09"-"\uAB0E",
"\uAB11"-"\uAB16",
"\uAB20"-"\uAB26",
"\uAB28"-"\uAB2E",
"\uAB30"-"\uAB5A",
"\uAB5C"-"\uAB5F",
"\uAB64",
"\uAB65",
"\uABC0"-"\uABE2",
"\uAC00"-"\uD7A3",
"\uD7B0"-"\uD7C6",
"\uD7CB"-"\uD7FB",
"\uF900"-"\uFA6D",
"\uFA70"-"\uFAD9",
"\uFB00"-"\uFB06",
"\uFB13"-"\uFB17",
"\uFB1D",
"\uFB1F"-"\uFB28",
"\uFB2A"-"\uFB36",
"\uFB38"-"\uFB3C",
"\uFB3E",
"\uFB40",
"\uFB41",
"\uFB43",
"\uFB44",
"\uFB46"-"\uFBB1",
"\uFBD3"-"\uFD3D",
"\uFD50"-"\uFD8F",
"\uFD92"-"\uFDC7",
"\uFDF0"-"\uFDFB",
"\uFE70"-"\uFE74",
"\uFE76"-"\uFEFC",
"\uFF21"-"\uFF3A",
"\uFF41"-"\uFF5A",
"\uFF66"-"\uFFBE",
"\uFFC2"-"\uFFC7",
"\uFFCA"-"\uFFCF",
"\uFFD2"-"\uFFD7",
"\uFFDA"-"\uFFDC"
] > }
```